# How to expose Minishift's IP from VMware to the host machine

Tags: openshift, vmware, minishift

My host machine is Window 10 x64.
I have VMware station with Ubuntu 16.04 where I installed Minishift (a nested VM in the Ubuntu VMware) and I have also Minikube installed.

Host IP:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6.68
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6.254
```

Ubuntu VMware IP (`ens33`):

```
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e5:0a:01  
          inet addr:10.0.62.4  Bcast:10.0.63.255  Mask:255.255.252.0

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:ca:91:14  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

virbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:fa:f3:cb  
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

The Minishift VM IP:

```
192.168.42.253:8443
```

From Ubuntu VMware I can access `192.168.42.253:8443` via the browser.
I have ping from the host machine to the Ubuntu VMware (10.0.62.4) but I can't access the Minishift IP (`192.168.42.253:8443`) from the host.

How can I expose Minishift to the host ?
Should I add some new routing on my host machine ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, but I run a Minishift 1.30 instance in Windows 10 host (using the git-cmd shell to run it), then I interact with it from my Fedora 27 VM.

I believe I decided on this set up because the minishift instance couldn't see the outside world (to resolve containers to download) when it was inside my VM.

Aside: I use VirtualBox, not VMWare, as I prefer its seamless mode.